# How do I draw this exact gradient on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, core-graphics, gradient

The gradient in question is [Figure 8-5](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_shadings/dq_shadings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH207-BBCFBHJF) from the Quartz 2D Programming Guide, "A radial gradient that varies between a point and a circle".

I'm trying to build a CGGradient object (not a CGShading object, which might be the problem) like so:

```
CGColorSpaceRef rgb = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGFloat colors[] =
{
    0, 0, 0, 0.9,
    0, 0, 0, 0
};
CGGradientRef gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents(rgb, colors, NULL, sizeof(colors)/(sizeof(colors[0])*sizeof(CGFloat)));
CGContextClipToRect(context, rect);
CGContextDrawRadialGradient(context, gradient, startCenter, startRadius, endCenter, endRadius, gradientDrawingOptions);
CGGradientRelease(gradient);
CGColorSpaceRelease(rgb);
```

Of course, that isn't exactly right -- the centre points and radii are correct, but the actual gradient doesn't look the same. I just wish Apple had provided the source code for each example! >:(

Comment: Did you check how many components are expected using `CGColorSpaceGetNumberOfComponents`? Have you verified that the component order (alpha first vs. alpha last) is what you expected? Are you trying to fade from zero-alpha 90% blue to zero-alpha black, or 90%-alpha black to zero-alpha black?

Comment: You see, Peter, I don't know what I should be expecting as values to draw that Figure 8-5 -- that's essentially my question -- because if I did, I would have just punched them in! :) I have an existing circle already drawn, and I'm just trying to draw a gradient as a shading layer on top of it.

Comment: `sizeof(colors)/(sizeof(colors[0])*sizeof(CGFloat))` is kind of coincidence isn't it that `CGFloat` and rgba both just happen to be `4`?

Comment: @slf: Indeed! `sizeof(colors[0])` and `sizeof(CGFloat)` say the same thing (since the elements of `colors` are `CGFloat`s), so this divides the size of the array by the size of each element *squared*. Given an array of eight elements, as shown, and assuming that a `CGFloat` is four bytes on the target architecture, this means that the value Shaggy Frog is passing for `count` is (after conversion to integer) zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:** These color values add the shading on top of other content (drawing from a point out to a circle):

```
CGFloat colors[] =
{
    0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.75f
};
```

Using these color values is pretty close (drawing from a point out to a circle):

```
CGFloat colors[] =
{
    0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.75f
};
```

Comment: Let's say I already have a filled circle underneath it that (with an arbitrary colour). How can I draw a gradient over top to approximate the shading?

Comment: Okay, so given your new set of values, you must be drawing from the inside of the circle out, correct? Right now I'm drawing from the outside in. (Our two arrays are almost identical that way)

Comment: Correct. Good point, you did not post that code, so there was no way to know. What is the issue then? It looks very close...

Comment: For some reason, to my eye, it seems a little off. Here's the rendering in the simulator (my "end circle" is located around the edge on the right side): http://www.shaggyfrog.com/junk/shaded-circle.png  How does it look to your eye?

Comment: Where is your point relative to your circle? My circle has a radius of 100 and the point's center is up and to the left of the circle's center by 50 each.

Comment: My start circle has a radius of 150. The end circle has a radius of 0, with a centre located on the edge of the start circle (just off the 3 o'clock mark)

Comment: That makes sense, but if you want it to look like that example from Apple, the point (circle with radius 0) should be between 10 and 11 o'clock and inside the (outer) circle rather than on the edge...

Comment: The default range of all four color components is 0.0 to 1.0. “0, 200, 100” is effectively 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, or pure cyan (assuming these are RGBA and not ARGB).